# R: Mixed Effects Cox Regression with several cluster-hierarchies

Tags: r, mixed-model, survival, cox-model

I'm attempting to model a cox-regression with several cluster hierarchies.

Suppose you want to model the hazard-rate of dropping out of high school. A cluster could for example be each classroom, but it could also be each school - and even each school district.

How would you go about implementing this in R?

Right now my "code" takes the form:

```
library(survival)
fit <- coxph(formula = Surv(days,censor) ~ variables, data=dataset, cluster = classroomID))
```

Using the following does not seem to work

```
..., cluster = c(classroomID,schoolID))
```

The research question is centered around the effect of a set of variables, and not the clusters - I merely want to control for the unobserved correlation within the clusters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do better with a package dedicated to mixed models. It seems like `coxme` in R is a widely used package. The syntax is very close to the `lme4` package, which is kind of the standard package for linear mixed models in R.